# How to position an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.borderBox {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.uniqueClickMetricsContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.uniqueClickMetrics {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.border {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: solid 2px #cccccc;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: 3px;
}

.restUniqueClickPercentage{
  
}

.topOneUniqueClickPercentage{
  
}

.topTwoUniqueClickPercentage{
  
}
```

```html
<div class="count-div">
  <div class="uniqueClickMetricsContainer">
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="restUniqueClickPercentage">2%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="restUniqueClickCount">8</span>
    </div>
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="topOneUniqueClickPercentage">40%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="topOneUniqueClickCount">99</span>
    </div>
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="topTwoUniqueClickPercentage">22%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="topTwoUniqueClickCount">98</span>
    </div>
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="topThreeUniqueClickPercentage">0%</span>
      <span class="border"></span> <span class="topThreeUniqueClickCount">97</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to position few of HTML elements under count-div relative to borderBox but I am able to position only the first element which is adjacent to the borderBox element, my question is how do I position all element after borderBox relative to borderBox only.As you can see In the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emozsaurab/kog3h65v/14/) border is not positioned properly as it is relative to its previous element but I want to position it relative to borderBox .

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/emozsaurab/kog3h65v/14/)

Comment: can you please share an image, how really you want the UI.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/emozsaurab/kog3h65v/14/ I want those straight line aligned properly

Comment: I am not understanding your question. can you please share a screenshot of your design. and try to remove flex-direction:column for .uniqueClickMetricsContainer if you need all the elements in one line.

Comment: @anji I want those borders ( | ) aligned as straight lines (one below another), right now they are not in proper position

Comment: So you need something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/4c3JF16afOMemn0BWc3Q?p=preview ?

Comment: @NiK648 thanks a lot,is there any way you can aligh number also in straight line,as single digits are left

Comment: Just add `text-align: left;` to those classes. Updated the sample.

Comment: @NiK648 may you can also explain the same in answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i m not understanding your question but i think u are asking that

```css
.borderBox {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.uniqueClickMetricsContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.uniqueClickMetrics {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.border {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: solid 2px #cccccc;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

span.actual {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="count-div">
  <div class="uniqueClickMetricsContainer">
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="restUniqueClickPercentage actual">2%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="restUniqueClickCount">8</span>
    </div>
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="topOneUniqueClickPercentage actual">40%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="topOneUniqueClickCount">99</span>
    </div>
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="topTwoUniqueClickPercentage actual">22%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="topTwoUniqueClickCount">98</span>
    </div>
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="topThreeUniqueClickPercentage actual">0%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="topThreeUniqueClickCount">97</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, so approve my answer as right answer by clicking in green arrow

Comment: it would be great, if you can explain how you achieved that.

Comment: if u want to give fixed width to span you need to give inline-block css to span. so i given one same class to all %  span and give width. ok !!

Comment: ok.thanks and .borderBox:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  } is better

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove left: 3px; for **border** class.

```css
.borderBox {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.uniqueClickMetricsContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.uniqueClickMetrics {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.border {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: solid 2px #cccccc;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.restUniqueClickPercentage{
  
}

.topOneUniqueClickPercentage{
  
}

.topTwoUniqueClickPercentage{
  
}
```

```html
<div class="count-div">
  <div class="uniqueClickMetricsContainer">
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="restUniqueClickPercentage">2%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="restUniqueClickCount">8</span>
    </div>
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="topOneUniqueClickPercentage">40%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="topOneUniqueClickCount">99</span>
    </div>
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="topTwoUniqueClickPercentage">22%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="topTwoUniqueClickCount">98</span>
    </div>
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="topThreeUniqueClickPercentage">0%</span>
      <span class="border"></span> <span class="topThreeUniqueClickCount">97</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution. Read comments in CSS for detail.

```css
.borderBox {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.uniqueClickMetricsContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.uniqueClickMetrics {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.border {
  /* not necessary= box-sizing: border-box; */
  border-right: solid 2px #cccccc;
  font-size: 30px;
  /* not necessary= position: relative; */
  /* delete= left: 3px; */
  vertical-align: middle /* i added for vertical alignment */
}

/* Use this class for percentage spans */
[class$="Percentage"]{
  display:inline-block; /* to apply width value */
  width:35px; /* width for spans */
  padding-left: 5px /* optional */
}

/* Use this class for count spans */
[class$="Count"]{
  padding-left: 10px /* optional */
}
```

```html
<div class="count-div">
  <div class="uniqueClickMetricsContainer">
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="restUniqueClickPercentage">2%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="restUniqueClickCount">8</span>
    </div>
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="topOneUniqueClickPercentage">40%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="topOneUniqueClickCount">99</span>
    </div>
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="topTwoUniqueClickPercentage">22%</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
      <span class="topTwoUniqueClickCount">98</span>
    </div>
    <div class="uniqueClickMetrics">
      <span class=borderBox>Hello</span>
      <span class="topThreeUniqueClickPercentage">0%</span>
      <span class="border"></span> <span class="topThreeUniqueClickCount">97</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```